# Cannot publish to Git hub, Publish To GitHub option is not available in VS 2019

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

I tried:

1. File -> Add To Source Control
2. Team Explorer -> Publish to Github
   It worked and the existing project was uploaded on my GitHub account.
   But, when I tried uploading via a different system following the same steps, then Add To Source Control option was not available in File and neither was Publish To GitHub option in team explorer.
   VS was logged into to a valid Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "via a different system", the extension probably is not installed in that system. Github for Visual studio is a 3rd party Extension.

Refer: https://visualstudio.github.com/